# PHP combine the value of one array with value of second array into a third custom array

Tags: php, arrays

I searched the most topics and couldn't find something that helps me out.

I have the following 2 arrays from form submit

```
Array
(
    [0] => FDS
    [1] => FSS
)
Array
(
    [0] => test@test.com
    [1] => 0123456789
)
```

and I need to combine the values from the first array with the values of the second array and make a custom third array that should look like this:

```
Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [code] => FDS
                    [info] => test@test.com
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [code] => SM2
                    [info] => 0123456789
                )

        )
```

The html form inputs looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="code[]" value="FDS">
<input id="flexDeliveryEmailInput" type="text" name="info[]">
<input id="flexDeliverySMS" type="checkbox" name="code[]" value="FSS">
<input type="text" name="info[]">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following form inputs instead:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="data[0][code]" value="FDS">
<input id="flexDeliveryEmailInput" type="text" name="data[0][info]">
<input id="flexDeliverySMS" type="checkbox" name="data[1][code]" value="FSS">
<input type="text" name="data[1][info]">
```

This will provide the merged array as you want it.